# Check list box before entering a record

Tags: c#, asp.net

In `ASP.NET/C#` how to check if the `listbox` has a duplicate value before entering a value from `textbox`.

I tried

```
If(ListBox1.Items.Contains(TextBox1.Text))
{
 // do nothing
}
else
{
 ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
}
```

I am getting error at first line.

Comment: Error 1 `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Contains(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\spam\spam_whitelist.aspx.cs 19 17 C:\...\spam\
` errorr 2 `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\spam\spam_whitelist.aspx.cs 19 41 C:\...\spam\
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like this

```
 if (ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(ListBox1.Items.FindByValue(TextBox1.Text.Trim())) == -1)
 {
      // value is not exist (insert new)

 }
```

Comment: What sense of calling IndexOf on list item? Maybe better rewrite `if(ListBox1.Items.FindByValue(TextBox1.Text) == null){  }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ls.Items.FindByText(TextBox1.Text) != null
```

It might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ListBox1.Items.FindByText(TextBox1.Text) == null)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check value of listboxitem not the listboxitem itself

```
bool contains = false;

foreach(ListItem item in ListBox1.items)
{
    if(item.value.equals(TextBox1.text)
        contains = true;
}

if(!contains)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
```

or if you can use linq

```
   if(!listBox.Items.Any(item => item.Value.Equals(textBox.text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

ListBox.Items is a collection of ListItems, this works:

```
ListItem new_item = new ListItem(TextBox1.Text);
if (!ListBox1.Items.Contains(new_item))
    {
    ListBox1.Items.Add(new_item);
    }
else
    {
    // handle duplicates
    }
```